# Can't Log In to Mobile App via Open ID

Tags: bug, ios-app

I just downloaded the SE application on my iPhone and was excited to be able to use my phone to access SE without having to use Safari when I can't use my laptop, but upon attempting to log in the page displays an error saying `client_id rejected`. Any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.3.2 which is currently in Apple's review queue.  I passed the wrong parameter when building the URL so `client_id` was the wrong value.